# ERROR: Module php7.0 does not exist!

Tags: php7

I have Ubuntu Server 16.04 installed with Webmin 1.831.  I am getting this error when trying to run PHP ERROR: Module php7.0 does not exist

libapache2-mod-php7.0 is installed.

Comment: Hi Dominic, sorry what command are you trying to run? It is missing from the question, thanks.

Comment: I am running the command: a2enmod php7.0

Im trying to install ruTorrent, this requires the installation of Apache and PHP.  I noticed that PHP was not working and when I run a2enmod php7.0 to verify if PHP is working I get the error above.

Comment: More info, when I install libapache2-mod-php7.0 I get this error:
`Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of `sudo apt-get install -f libapache2-mod-php7.0`? Thanks.

Answer (score 56):

```
sudo apt purge libapache2-mod-php7.0 libapache2-mod-php
```

then

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0 libapache2-mod-php
```

fixed it.

Comment: Finally this, was that did it for me!
In ubuntu 18.04 you can use `php7.2` too.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (ubuntu 18 & php 7.2), did try `php7.2`, even the answers below!, looks like apache2 isn't recognize php!

Comment: It works on Ubuntu 22.04. Thank you!

Answer (score 22):

I have faced the same problem and Here is the solution:

You have to install an additional package:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Now run

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

to enable it

Restart the server

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Answer (score 9):

For the latest php version as of Nov. 2020, I solved the same problem with the following commands - in that order.

```sh
$ sudo apt purge libapache2-mod-php7.4 libapache2-mod-php
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.4
$ sudo a2enmod php7.4
$ sudo service apache2 stop
$ sudo service apache2 start
```

Comment: php7.4 doesnt exist

Comment: @chx101 `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.4` works for me

Comment: this worked for me Jan 2021.  The accepted answer did not

Comment: I am using Nginx web service. would it work for Nginx?

Comment: thanks for this. None of the above worked for me but this

Comment: This fixed an Apache2 update problem for me. The error was `info: Executing deferred 'a2enmod php7.4' for package libapache2-mod-php7.4

ERROR: Module php7.4 does not exist!

dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):

 installed apache2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1`