# can't get PHP running on apache, having run these commands to set up apache with php

Tags: apache2, php

can't get PHP running on apache, having run these commands to set up apache with php

I have an ubuntu machine, and have been trying to get PHP running..

As you can see the PHP isn't running

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2# cat /var/www/html/index.php
<?php
echo 4+3;
?>
xyz
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2#

root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2# curl 127.0.0.1/index.php
<?php
echo 4+3;
?>
xyz
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2#
```

I tried `apt-get update` , `apt-get upgrade`, `apt-get purge apache2`  ,    `apt-get install apache2`,  `apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php`  ,  `systemctl restart apache2`

Still same result.

Comment: What's the result? What version of Ubuntu are you running? At a glance, I would question whether Apache is configured to default to `.php` instead of the default `.html` …

Comment: @Matigo can't you see the curl command I showed there? It references index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP must be enabled in Apache. Run

```
sudo a2enmod php7.4  # or whatever version of libapache2-mod-php7.X is installed
```

and restart Apache.

Comment: thanks.. that gave `ERROR: Module php7 does not exist!` but combined with https://askubuntu.com/questions/912638/error-module-php7-0-does-not-exist  Rodgers-Ategyeka's answer of `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.4
` worked.

Comment: strange that  quite a few webpages on installing php on ubuntu don't mention that a2enmod  e.g.  .https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-php-on-ubuntu-18-04/  or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04  Maybe it's a newer thing?

Comment: @barlop  looks like by default php enables itself(tested on fresh ubuntu installation) so it's a mystery what disabled it but that command enables it.