# Apache DocumentRoot

Tags: server, apache2, php, root

I have a Apache installed on Ubuntu 18. Config file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf does not contain DocumentRoot directive. But there is **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default** which defines DocumentRoot as /var/www/html. Directory /var/www/html contains index.php file with simple `<? phpinfo() ?>` but if I try to call servers IP from browser like http://40.69.5.143/ it does not show www/html/index.php but **it opens the first directory in /var/www/html and its index.php**. I dont understand why it ignores 000-default config file.
000-default looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You need to enable PHP in Apache. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304741/

Comment: I dont think so. If php is disabled index.php should be dislayed as a text.

Comment: I have another domain on this server and php works fine https://camocloud.publicvm.com/

Comment: How many sites do you have enabled with Apache? Is there a `001-anothersite.conf` file and you are seeing *that* site when trying to access the PHP file in `/var/www/html`?